# clicking on a button using Webdriver and javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have seen many questions and solutions for clicking on a button using webdriver. I have tried various solutions and none seem to resolve my issue. Please help.  Here is my HTML snippet.

```
<b>
<input name="submit" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('submitClicked').value='Next';return true;" type="submit" tabindex="2" class="-opa-btn-primary nextButton" value="Next" alt="'Next'" id="submitNext">
</b>
```

I need to click on this "Next" button.

I tried:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("return document.getElementById('submitClicked').value='Next';return true;");
```

This didn't work, it gives exception saying document.getElementBy ID return null.

Next, I tried:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.Id("submitNext").isEnabled())
    driver.findElement(By.Id("submitNext").click();
```

This also didn't work.

Comment: I donno for some reason my HTML snippet is missed.Please find it below:<input name="submit" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('submitClicked').value='Next';return true;" type="submit" tabindex="2" class="-opa-btn-primary nextButton" value="Next" alt="'Next'" id="submitNext">

Comment: What happens with .click()?  Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: Why don't you try driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click()

Comment: I have tried all different means of clicking the button.But finding element by any means is not working as it throws NoSuchelementException.ALso using javascript Executor returns WebDriverException :document.getElementByID(...)is NUll

Comment: Am using FF 26.0,Windows 8,Selenium 2.39.0.Also I tried to use GetAttribute function to print values but it return null for few attributes and for few It returns somes trange string not relevant to this HTML snippet.

Comment: Maybe your button is not visible? Some drivers prevent interacting with an invisible (i.e. hidden by CSS) element.

Comment: How do I make this element visible and perform click()?Is there any alternative to this scenario in enabling the button and clicking?

Comment: Can your site be accessed publicly?If so post the url and the steps to get this button. .

Comment: No It cannot be accessed publicly.But from the screenshots taken I could see that the page is still not loaded as screenshot function when called even after considerable delay shows the previous page

Comment: Hi I have found the solution.It was in different frmae.SO I switched to that Frame and tried to access it worked.Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

With the given Info We can use ID for the submit button(submitNext)

Step 2:

Write a prototype for Visible Function

public static boolean isVisibleByID(String id)

{

try

{

```
  driver.findElement(By.id(id)).isEnabled();
  return true;
```

}

catch(Exception e)

{

```
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
```

}

}

Step 3:

if(isVisibleByID("submitNext"))
    driver.findElement(By.Id("submitNext").click();